# how can I link a image to a number android ?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I'm working on sliding puzzle and so far so good. I have a working puzzle but now I'm working with numbers no images. Now I would like to use images as a background for the number. Can any one help me to cut the images up and get them linked to the numbers so the puzzle still works?

This is my code for the numbers it's 9 piece puzzle

```
    public Button[] findButtons() {
    Button[] b = new Button[9];

    b[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button00);
    b[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    b[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    b[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    b[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    b[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
    b[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
    b[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
    b[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
    return b;
}

public void makeMove(final Button b) {
    bad_move=true;
    int b_text,b_pos,zuk_pos;
    b_text=Integer.parseInt((String) b.getText());
    b_pos=find_pos(b_text);
    zuk_pos=find_pos(0);
    switch(zuk_pos)
    {
    case(0):
        if(b_pos==1||b_pos==3)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(1):
        if(b_pos==0||b_pos==2||b_pos==4)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(2):
        if(b_pos==1||b_pos==5)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(3):
        if(b_pos==0||b_pos==4||b_pos==6)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(4):
        if(b_pos==1||b_pos==3||b_pos==5||b_pos==7)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(5):
        if(b_pos==2||b_pos==4||b_pos==8)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(6):
        if(b_pos==3||b_pos==7)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(7):
        if(b_pos==4||b_pos==6||b_pos==8)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    case(8):
        if(b_pos==5||b_pos==7)
            bad_move=false;
    break;
    }

    if(bad_move==true)
    {
        feedbackText.setText("Ongeldige zet");
        return;
    }
    feedbackText.setText("Geldige zet");
    cells.remove(b_pos);
    cells.add(b_pos, 0);
    cells.remove(zuk_pos);
    cells.add(zuk_pos,b_text);


    fill_grid();

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if(cells.get(i)!=goal[i])
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    feedbackText.setText("Voltooid");
    mChronometer.stop();
    long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();   
    tijd = (int) elapsedMillis;
    mScoreDialog = new ScoreDialog(this,this, 0, convertToTimeFormat(elapsedMillis));
    mScoreDialog.show();
}

public void fill_grid()
{
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        int text=cells.get(i);
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = 
                (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)buttons[text].getLayoutParams();
        switch(i)
        {case(0):

            absParams.x = 5;
        absParams.y = 5;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(1):

            absParams.x = 110;
        absParams.y = 5;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(2):

            absParams.x = 215;
        absParams.y = 5;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(3):

            absParams.x = 5;
        absParams.y = 110;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(4):

            absParams.x =110;
        absParams.y =110;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(5):

            absParams.x = 215;
        absParams.y =110;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(6):

            absParams.x = 5;
        absParams.y = 215;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(7):

            absParams.x = 110;
        absParams.y = 215;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;
        case(8):

            absParams.x = 215;
        absParams.y = 215;
        buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
        break;


        }


    }

}

public int find_pos(int element)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if(cells.get(i)==element)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

As you can see I'm validating the moves and using imagebuttons.

Answer (score 0):

Save images in `res/drawable` as `img_1.png`, ...`img_10.png`;

Create a map:

```
static final HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<~>();
map.put(1,R.drawable.img_1);
. . .
map.put(10,R.drawable.img_10);
```

get drawable id for a number:

```
map.get(7);
```